# create column based on multiple if condition

Tags: pandas

For example I have the following DataFrame:

| A header | header. 1 | header. 2 | header. 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 111 | 121 | 323 |
| Second | 222 | 212 | 232 |

I want my new column to be based on the following if condition:
if (value in df.header1 > than 0, then add 2) and (value in df.header2 is between 2 and 3, then add 5) and (value in df.header3 and < 400, then add 11)

so my new df would look like this:

| A header | header. 1 | header. 2 | header. 3 | condition_head |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 111 | 121 | 323 | 13 |
| Second | 222 | 212 | 232 | 12 |

Comment: What's going on with 12 in `df['condition_head']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your logic use:

```
df['output'] = (df['header.1'].gt(0) * 2 +
                df['header.2'].between(2,3) * 5 +
                df['header.3'].lt(400) * 11 )
```

Output:

```
  A header  header. 1  header. 2  header. 3  output
0    First        111        121        323      13
1   Second        222        212        232      13
```

I'm not sure how you get to your expected output.

Comment: This should be the accepted of the 3. I forgot about the built-in methods

Answer (score 1):

```
df['condition_head'] = 0
df['condition_head'] += 2 * (df['header.1'] > 0)
df['condition_head'] += 5 * (df['header.2'] > 2 and df['header.2'] < 3)
df['condition_head'] += 11 * (df['header.3'] > 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and a self defined `helper` function:

```
def helper(x):
    ans= 0
    if 0< x['header.1']:
        ans+=2
    if 2< x['header.2']<=3:
        ans+=5
    if x['header.3']<400:
        ans+=11
    return ans
df['contition_head'] = df.apply(helper, axis=1)
```